# Advice with String and Char array

Tags: android

For the application I am working on ,I want my text to be displayed as ticker text and I am using a Notification for that, the constructor is Notification(int,char array[],when).The problem is the second argument should be a char array but all I have is a string, now would the string serve the same purpose ,if I use it instead of the char array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert strings into char-array by using `toCharArray()` method on string.

```
//for example
char[] array = "this is my string".toCharArray();
```

However, in [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html), its [CharSequence](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html) at second place in constructor, not array of characters. And in this case,yes,  you can use **strings** too.

> Notification(int icon, CharSequence tickerText, long when)